# Detecting Circles with Partial Edges (MATLAB for Cell Growth on Microcarriers)

Tags: matlab, geometry, object-detection, image-segmentation, medical-imaging

I am attempting to develop software that will determine the confluency of the cells we are producing on microcarriers. To do that you need to determine the area occupied by the cells divided by the area available for the cells to grow. So 100% confluency would mean the microcarriers are completely covered.

In order to do that, we need to identify the microcarriers which are spherical but the edges don't show up with one of our imaging techniques.

I've played around with most of the variables in imfindcircles() but I am having no luck with these images.

**Any suggestions on how to detect circles when the edges are bumpy and incomplete** along with the corresponding radius and center? (Green = cells)

[Sample Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faDgb.jpg)

Comment: That’s not the original image, you’ve already modified it heavily. If you post the original image you will be much more likely to receive useful help.

Comment: ImageJ have multiple tools/plugins for (semi-) automatic cell/particle/vesicle detection and measurement. If you are fond of the MATLAB environment, these two can easily linked through Java interfaces.